# How do I initialize a default "data" value to the returned value of a callback function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, promise, es6-promise

I am running into an issue being able to initialize a value on App.vue to the result of a function when that function is async.  I also tried setting it to the resolution of a promise but that didn't seem to work either.  In the former case I just get an undefined value, and in the second I just get the ref type for a js promise.  What is the proper way in Vue to initialize a variable to the result of a callback that will complete at a later time?

Comment: please share your code in order to see the issue clearer

Comment: Can you show what you have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to do this in the [`created` lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).  Once the async action is complete, the result is stored in the data prop.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    asyncData: null
  },
  created() {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
    axios.get(url).then(response => {
        this.asyncData = response.data;
    });
  }
})
```

Template:

```html
<div id="app">
    {{ asyncData }}
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/dk1h7fgL)